# Including a variable in a GAMM more than once (in R)

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model

I've constructed a GAMM on some environmental variables (water temp., salinity, etc..) to see if there are significant differences between the months in which we collect data. Values obviously change by month and year (time of day and location too), but I'd still like to test each month in a pairwise comparison later (temp in March vs. April, etc).

My question: **Can a variable be included in a model more than once?** I know I need an interaction term between month and year, but do I also need two random effects for both variables as well?

Modelling temperature (temp = temperature; time2 = time of day (over all sites/months/years):

[image]

[image]

Model:

```
mod <- gam(temp ~ s(Month2, bs = "re") + s(CYR, bs = "re") + s(Month2, CYR, bs = "re") + s(time2, bs = "cr") + s(Site, bs = "re"), family = gaussian, data = env)
```

My data:

```
> str(env)
tibble [1,363 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ use_for_analysis: chr [1:1363] "Standard" "Standard" "Standard" "Standard" ...
 $ Date            : POSIXct[1:1363], format: "2011-01-07" "2011-01-07" "2011-01-07" ...
 $ CYR             : Factor w/ 18 levels "2005","2006",..: 7 7 7 5 7 7 7 7 7 5 ...
 $ Season          : Factor w/ 2 levels "DRY","WET": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Month           : num [1:1363] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Time            : POSIXct[1:1363], format: "1899-12-31 10:05:00" "1899-12-31 10:38:00" "1899-12-31 10:55:00" ...
 $ time2           : POSIXct[1:1363], format: "2022-12-01 10:05:00" "2022-12-01 10:38:00" "2022-12-01 10:55:00" ...
 $ DT              : POSIXct[1:1363], format: "2011-01-07 10:05:00" "2011-01-07 10:38:00" "2011-01-07 10:55:00" ...
 $ Site            : Factor w/ 47 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 46 44 43 22 45 47 42 33 34 19 ...
 $ temp            : num [1:1363] 17.6 18.4 18.6 18.8 18.8 ...
 $ sal             : num [1:1363] 31.2 30.3 29.9 18.5 31.3 ...
 $ DO              : num [1:1363] 6.12 6.65 6.29 6.56 7.25 ...
 $ water_depth     : num [1:1363] 39 42 58 36 58 70 68 71 40 67 ...
 $ sed_depth       : num [1:1363] 31 143 89 28 111 31 123 29 42 2 ...
 $ Month2          : Factor w/ 8 levels "Jan","Feb","Mar",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to model month as a random effect? The effect of "month" on water temperature is highly likely to be smooth plus some random variation, so why not `s(Month)`?. Why does the long term trend need to be random? Is that what you honestly expect, that there's no relationships between years?

Comment: This is mostly a result of my own ignorance on the subject (mixed models). I think there is a relationship between month and year (it's not "random"/unrelated to the previous year), but I don't fully understand how to model that in a GAMM. Especially if my main goal is multiple comparisons (to humor my supervisor's idea to compare months to see how much each differs, on average - i.e, do Jan. and Feb. differ that much? By how much, on average?). I think s(Month2, bs = "cr", k=8) would work better though (k=8 because I don't have the full 12 months).

Comment: As a side note, I also thought random effects were for categorical variables with many (10+) levels.

Comment: I'm not saying that modelling month as a ranef is completely wrong. What I'm saying is that you took something that is continuous (time through a year, seasonal time) and turned it into a categorical variable. If you'd left it as a numeric variable and modelled it as a smooth via `s(month, k = 8)` you likely will get a easier to understand model. Then you can do things like `s(month, yearf, bs = "fs", k = 8)` to get a random smooth of seasonal time for each year (where `yearf` is coded as a factor!) or...

Comment: `te(month, year, k = c(8,10))` where we treat each temporal variable as a continuous variable and model them smoothly via a tensor product interaction to allow the seasonal effect to vary with the trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate answer to your question is "yes" but you need to be careful to not include the main effects of the variable in question more than once. In the case of your model where you have modelled everything as random effects, then there is no problem.

An alternative model might be

```r
gam(temp ~ s(Month2, k = 8) +
           s(CYR) +
           ti(Month2, CYR, k = c(5,5)) +
           s(time2, bs = "cr") +
           ti(Month2, time2) +
           ti(CYR, time2, k = c(5,5)) +
           s(Site, bs = "re"),
    family = gaussian, data = env
    method = "REML") # <--- Important or "ML"
```

where I have used "main effects" smooths with `s()` and "tensor product interaction" smooths with `ti()` — which exclude the main effects from the tensor product — to include smooths of multiple the same variable to allow the within day, within season, and between year effects to all interact.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Quick question, R didn't seem to like my "time2" variable in the GAMM and I kept getting this error: "Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]". Using the "unclass" function made the error go away s(unclass(time2), bs = "cr")), but I'm afraid I may have unknowingly created a new problem. Is this a proper fix to that error? Have you encountered this before?

Comment: I also get this error: Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: You need to code random effect variables as factors (for the `bs="re"` bits, or if using `gamm()` or `gamm4::gamm4()` the variables you include in the ranef argument) for `ti()` or general smooths with `s` you need to have numerical, not factors